# What does "the sound" indicate?

Tags: definite-article

> A team of biologists at the University of California recently
> examined the laughter of animals. They published their findings in the
> journal, Bioacoustics, on April 19. In total, the researchers
> identified 65 species of animals that made certain sounds during play.
> The actual noise was different from human laughter and varied
> depending on the species. For example, a rat produced an ultrasonic
> trill, while a bottlenose dolphin* whistled and squawked. Meanwhile,
> monkeys and primates quietly panted, grunted, and even smacked their
> lips. However, the function and intent of **the sound** were akin to those
> of human laughter. The animals especially laughed during play behavior
> that could be confused with fighting. By vocalizing laughter, they
> were communicating that the interaction was playful and not meant to
> be aggressive. The researchers said they were able to find instances
> of playful laughter among mammals and two species of birds known for
> their social behavior.

I want to know what the sound (bold) indicates.

A. **the sound** indicates the sound of monkeys and primates

B. **the sound** indicates the sound of a rat's ultrasonic trill, a bottlenose dolphin's whistling, and monkeys and primates

Answer (score 2):

I would understand it to mean (B) *and* the other 62 animal sounds which the writers equate to human laughter. The three they mention specifically are given as examples.